# ZXing performance on Android

Tags: android

I installed the zxing-2.0 source (android version 4) into an Eclipse project, compiled the android CaptureActivity project with the core.jar linked in and it works fine on my device.  However, when I compare the performance with the version that I download from Android market, mine is MUCH slower to recognize a 2-d barcode.  Any thoughts on the differences between my Eclipse compiled version and the Android marker download version as regards speed to actually process the camera image?  They are both version 4 as observed in Android manage applications.

Comment: do the apk sizes differ?

Comment: the version downloaded from Android market is smaller (0.93 MB) than my compiled version (1.20 MB)

Comment: I don't know what would cause it. But I feel you should consider it a reason to integrate with zxing via intent rather than trying to compile and embed it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what this means - you mean that core.jar is probably not the issue - ie the problem is somewhere in the user interface or camera management?

Comment: Nope, I mean I don't know what the problem could be. But I think you should consider this a reason to use the scan via intent that barcode scanner provides http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent instead of trying to compile and include your own copy within your application.

Comment: Is your compiled version debug or release?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess at the difference is that you did not compile with Proguard optimization / shrinking, while we do. I agree with Tim that this is yet another reason you don't want to copy and paste our `android/` code, which we discourage.

Comment: I'll try the optimization just to close the loop on the difference.  I'll also use the android/ as just a sample and take Tim's advice on actual implementation.  Thanks all!